# Determine the location(s) in character vector that match maximum number of matches from a match vector [R]

Tags: r, string, match

How can I test which element of a character vector (testvec) has the most words from another character vector (matchvec)?

```
testvec <- c("making words up here for a test significant words",
             "this one is really important and significant/crucial",
             "can you see which has most significant/important words?",
             "this one isn't desired at all")

matchvec <- c("important", "significant", "crucial")

desired_result (since the second from testvec has the most words from matchvec)
[1] 2
```

If I change it so that two have the same max I want to return both indexes:

```
matchvec2 <- c("important", "significant")

desired_result2 (since the second/third from testvec have the most words from matchvec2)
    [1] 2
    [2] 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility using `stringr` could be:

```
count <- str_count(testvec, paste(matchvec, collapse = "|"))
which(count == max(count))

[1] 2
```

The same with just `base R`:

```
count <- rowSums(sapply(matchvec, function(x) grepl(x, testvec)))
which(count == max(count))
```

Or if there are repeated words (as proposed by @Henrik):

```
count <- lengths(gregexpr(paste(matchvec, collapse = "|"), testvec))
which(count == max(count))
```

Comment: Another `base` possibility: `len <- lengths(gregexpr(paste(matchvec, collapse = "|"), testvec))`; `which(len == max(len))`

Comment: A note, the base R approach does not work if the words repeat, e.g. `"important important important important important"`

Comment: @Henrik very nice possibility. Added it to my post. If you wish to post it yourself, I can remove it :)

Comment: @tmfmnk I had no intention to post an own answer, so your edit is perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility:

```
 res<-lapply(testvec, function(x) stringr::str_count(matchvec)) 
which.max(Map(sum,res))
[1] 2
```

Or use a purely `tidyverse` solution and extract the indices that are true:

```
plyr::ldply(testvec,
            function(x)
              all(stringr::str_count(x,matchvec)>0))
 which(res==TRUE)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```r
testvec <- c("making words up here for a test significant words", "this one is really important and significant/crucial", "can you see which has most significant/important words?", "this one isn't desired at all")

matchvec <- c("important", "significant", "crucial")

matches <- sapply(testvec, 
       function(x){sum(sapply(matchvec,
                              function(y){
                                grepl(y,x)
                              }))})

matches[matches == max(matches)]
#> this one is really important and significant/crucial 
#>                                                    3
```

And if you do only want to have the positions returned use `which`:

```
which(matches == max(matches)])
```